# When is log-convexity inequality for Gamma function tight?

Tags: functional-analysis, gamma-function

Is the following is a well known inequality for the Gamma function.
If $\alpha \in  [0,1]$ then 
\begin{align}
\Gamma \left( (1-\alpha)x+\alpha y \right) \le \Gamma^\alpha \left(  x \right)\Gamma^{1-\alpha} \left(  y \right)
\end{align}

For which instance is this inequality tight (except trivial once $\alpha=0,1$)? I tried a few example the were almost there but not exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality is tight only for the trivial cases $\alpha=0,1$, because the function $\log\Gamma(x)$ is *strictly* convex in the interval $(0,\infty)$. This means that for any $x<y$, the graph of the chord connecting the points $(x,\log\Gamma(x))$ and $(y,\log\Gamma(y))$ will be strictly above the graph, touching it only at those two points, which correspond to $\alpha=0,1$.

Comment: I see, thanks. Is there anything else in terms of how good this inequality we can say?